# Substituting main diagonal elements when a condition is satisfied

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

I'm trying to substitute the main diagonal elements when their value is less or equal to zero.
I've tried the following:

```
testmat = {{0, 1, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 1}};
ReplacePart[testmat, {i_, i_} -> $MachineEpsilon /; # <= 0 &]
```

This doesn't work. I've also used

```
ReplacePart[testmat, Position[testmat, # <= 0 &]-> $MachineEpsilon]
```

but doesn't work either. I've always had a bit a of trouble with patterns and rules. Any good bibliography recommendation is welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReplacePart[testmat, {i_, i_} /; testmat[[i, i]] <= 0 :> $MachineEpsilon]
```

> {{2.220446049250313*^-16, 1, 3}, {2, 2.220446049250313*^-16, 0}, {2,
>      4, 1}}

Also

```
ReplacePart[testmat, 
  Select[#[[1]] == #[[2]] &]@Position[testmat, _?(# <= 0 &)] :> $MachineEpsilon]
MapIndexed[If[Equal @@ #2 && # <= 0, $MachineEpsilon, #] &, testmat, {2}]
```

> same result

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, I don't get why the second line of code would give the same result... Where is the check of the pattern {i_,i_}?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The same with `While` and `If` - less elegant but perhaps easier to read. For your toy matrix, **maxi** the numbers of rows (columns), **i** the first column and **sth** the value you want to replace in the diagonal,

```
testmat = {{0, 1, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 1}};
maxi = 3;
i = 1;
sth = 10;
```

Then

```
While[i < maxi + 1, 
If[testmat[[i, i]] <= 0, 
testmat = ReplacePart[testmat, {i, i} -> sth],]; i++]
```

Output is

> {{10, 1, 3}, {2, 10, 0}, {2, 4, 1}}